# Can I upload edited screenshots to iTune Connect for App?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store-connect

ipa file was produced by third-party application (not xcode). 
I have real devices available to make 4/3.5 inch screenshots for iPhone and 9.7 inch screenshots for iPad.
But the essential screenshots on iTune Connect are 5.5 inch display iPhone and 12.9 inch display iPad (and I don't have the real devices for that).

If I photoshop screenshot for 5.5 inch and 12.9 inch according to its requiremnt as mentioned here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/Properties.html

> For 5.5 inch iPhone:
>
> - 72 dpi, RGB, flattened, no transparency
> - High-quality JPEG or PNG image file format
> - 1242 x 2208 pixels for hi-res portrait
> - 2208 x 1242 pixels for hi-res landscape
>
> For 12.7 inch iPad:
>
> - 72 dpi, RGB, flattened, no transparency
> - High-quality JPEG or PNG image file format
> - 2048 x 2732 pixels for hi-res portrait
> - 2732 x 2048 pixels for hi-res landscape

Will "Submit App Review" be ok? I mean whether somebody inside check the screenshot and make approval or not? **Will they approve for app publishing?** Or will they contact to make real-devices/stimulators screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the image meets the dimensions required, it doesn't matter how the image was produced.  You will see numerous images on the store that aren't actual screenshots; ie. they have additional text or information

Comment: Indeed, I have seen "screenshots" that are nothing but text describing the app. But I have also wondered whether that is really how Apple intends this feature to be used...

Comment: That doesn't sound right, I agree but, it's Apple, so who knows what they will approve in the future :)  The Human-interface guidelines say that the launch screen shouldn't be a "splash screen" but that is routinely ignored (and approved) as well.  I think in the context of this question it sounds like they want to produce something that is basically a screenshot but can't do it from the actual device (or simulator) rather than completely unrelated images

Answer (score 0):

**Yes,** You can submit your screenshot and submit your app for review.

It is not compulsory to create screenshot from actual device. You can photoshop too.

The must follow criteria is **The image size(Dimension)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit photoshop edited screenshot for this, you can create a screenshot using the Apple guidelines.

**P.S.** Please make sure that screenshot must be relevant to your app. Otherwise, the application could be got rejected.